# Python time delta

Tags: python, paramiko, timedelta

Please let me know if I am doing this part correctly. I am trying to grab files ONLY modified in the past 24 hours. However my output is ALL files in the directory regardless of modified time:

```
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
dayToStr = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr()
for file in file_list_attr:
  if  file.st_mtime <= dayToStr:
    print file
```

Output

> > > -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60        3404961 09 Jan 18:32 2_YEAR_912828UD0_20130109.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       10206411 09 Jan 18:32 3_YEAR_912828UG3_20130109.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       68311760 09 Jan 18:34 5_YEAR_912828UE8_20130109.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       54215712 09 Jan 18:35 7_YEAR_912828UF5_20130109.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       88014103 09 Jan 18:37 10_YEAR_912828TY6_20130109.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       53565072 09 Jan 18:38 30_YEAR_912810QY7_20130109.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60        8527412 04 Jan 18:31 2_YEAR_912828UD0_20130104.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       21659138 04 Jan 18:31 3_YEAR_912828UC2_20130104.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       91281894 04 Jan 18:34 5_YEAR_912828UE8_20130104.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       80421507 04 Jan 18:36 7_YEAR_912828UF5_20130104.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       108700356 04 Jan 18:38 10_YEAR_912828TY6_20130104.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       50204292 04 Jan 18:39 30_YEAR_912810QY7_20130104.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60        2319656 07 Jan 18:24 2_YEAR_912828UD0_20130107.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60        6978760 07 Jan 18:24 3_YEAR_912828UC2_20130107.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       53579177 07 Jan 18:25 5_YEAR_912828UE8_20130107.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       46069381 07 Jan 18:26 7_YEAR_912828UF5_20130107.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       70802355 07 Jan 18:28 10_YEAR_912828TY6_20130107.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       43050822 07 Jan 18:29 30_YEAR_912810QY7_20130107.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60        2713906 08 Jan 18:31 2_YEAR_912828UD0_20130108.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60        8889264 08 Jan 18:31 3_YEAR_912828UC2_20130108.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       63857903 08 Jan 18:32 5_YEAR_912828UE8_20130108.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       55544096 08 Jan 18:34 7_YEAR_912828UF5_20130108.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       89750161 08 Jan 18:36 10_YEAR_912828TY6_20130108.dat
> > >       -rw-r--r--   1 4012     60       59233399 08 Jan 18:37 30_YEAR_912810QY7_20130108.dat

Comment: What is file.st_mtime?  An integer?  A string?  I bet your comparing apples and oranges in terms of type.

Comment: In paramiko the following file attributes are available        Representation of the attributes of a file (or proxied file) for SFTP in client or server mode. It attemps to mirror the object returned by os.stat as closely as possible, so it may have the following fields, with the same meanings as those returned by an os.stat object:

    st_size
    st_uid
    st_gid
    st_mode
    st_atime
    st_mtime

Comment: @user1741381: Thank you for the detailed bug reports (below). They are helpful! However, it is frowned upon to put them in the answer section. Instead, please edit your original question to include the relevant bug details.

Answer (score 3):

`file.st_mtime` is an integer timestamp.
`dayToStr` is a string.

In Python2, `integers` **always** compare less than `strings` for the rather [arbitrary reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680/190597) that the `i` in `int` comes before the `s` in `str` alphabetically:

```
In [123]: 1234 < 'foobar'
Out[123]: True
```

In Python3, comparing an `int` to a `str` raises a TypeError:

```
>>> 1234 < 'foobar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

---

Instead, compare datetime objects:

```
import datetime as DT
import os

yesterday = DT.datetime.now() - DT.timedelta(days=1)
# or, if you want 00:00 AM, yesterday:
# yesterday = DT.datetime.now().replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0) - DT.timedelta(days=1)

file_list_attr = sftp.listdir_attr()
for pfile in file_list_attr:
    if DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(pfile.st_mtime) > yesterday:
        print pfile
```

---

References:

- [datetime.fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp): This was used to convert the timestamp to a `DT.datetime` object.
- [datetime.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace): This was suggested for setting the hours, minutes, seconds (of `yesterday`) back to zero.

Comment: @user1741381: In that case, you could use `DT.datetime.fromtimestamp` to convert the `file.st_mtime` timestamp into a datetime object.

Comment: Above, I've changed `yesterday` to be a `DT.datetime` rather than a `DT.date` object so it can be compared with the `DT.datetime` object returned by `DT.datetime.fromtimestamp`.

Comment: Thank you this worked flawlessly. I would like to better understand it though. I will certainly look it over

Answer (score 0):

Appears to fail when comparing to 'yesterday'

```
for pfile in file_list_attr:
    print DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(pfile.st_mtime)


2013-01-09 18:32:06
2013-01-09 18:32:22
2013-01-09 18:34:07
2013-01-09 18:35:27
2013-01-09 18:37:38

for pfile in file_list_attr:
    print DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(pfile.st_mtime) > yesterday



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 2, in <module>
    print DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(pfile.st_mtime) > yesterday
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of how you can:

1. list all the files in a directory
2. Print all the files that meet the condition of been modified 24h ago

   ```
       # Task: grab files ONLY modified in the past 24 hours

       import os
       import datetime

       myPath = "/users/george/documents/"

       # Adding all the files found in myFolder in a collection
       fileCollection = os.listdir(myPath)

       # Iterating through the files, printing their last modified date
       for i in fileCollection:
           # Getting the timestamp in a variable
           fileModTimeStamp = os.path.getmtime(myPath + str(i))
           fileModDateTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(fileModTimeStamp)

           # Calculating the time delta
           currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
           timeElapsed =  currentTime - fileModDateTime

           # 24h dimedelta
           twentyFourHours = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0) -  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

           # Print the files that meet the condition
           if timeElapsed <= twentyFourHours:
               print "The File: " + str(i) + " Was Last Modified At: " + str(fileModDateTime) + " ,Which was about: " \
                 + str(timeElapsed) + " ago."
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe the os module will work as I am using paramiko to SFTP to the remote host and perform actions on the files in the directory

```
for filename in file_list_attr:
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    print mtime



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 2, in <module>
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
  File "U:\ActivPy\lib\genericpath.py", line 54, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, SFTPAttributes found
```